# Modify a file by adding and deleting columns in-place using a Perl script

Tags: regex, perl

I am writing a Perl script where I know which columns are to be removed and and where it needs to be added. e,g I have a array called `deleteColumn` which contains a which number column is to be deleted. Similarly I have an array called `AddColumn` which contains information about the location where something needs to be inserted.

As input I have a line where columns are separated by commas `(,)`. An e.g of this would be:

`1,2,3,5,9,7,8,12`

Now value in array deleteColumn is say [4,7] which means I have to 
delete element 9 and 12. And value in array AddColumn is say [3,5]
these addColumn indicates an empty addition i.e `','`. So after deletion
and addition finally the output should look like:

`1,2,3,,5,,7,8.`

How can I achieve this inline as I would need to read around GB's of
files ( combined size ) and operate on them . Can this be done inline?

I am reading the file line by line.

Comment: So you have a large file which you need to re-write this way, delete and insert columns?  Is that the only processing you need to do?  What do you mean by "_inline_"?

Comment: Deleting the 4th and 7th columns (zero-indexed) from `1,2,3,5,9,7,8,12` leaves `1,2,3,5,7,8`, assuming you don't have to re-calculate the indexes after each deletion. Now adding an empty field before the 3rd and 5th columns gives `1,2,3,,5,7,,8`, again assuming you don't have to re-calculate the indexes after each change. Why is your expected output `1,2,3,,5,,7,8`?

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like you want to do all inserts and deletions simultaneously, not in series. It might help to clarify that in your post.

Comment: @zdim by inline i meant not  writing in a new file . But modify there when i read the line like sed -i

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot If you see the 3rd coloumn with zero indexing would be after `1,2,3` once `, ,` is inserted it becomes then it would be like `1,2,3,,5` and with zero indexing next 5th is after `1,2,3,,5` therefore `1,2,3,,5,,7,8`

Comment: @MiguelPrz I was trying cut but then that would need redirecting outputs to new file and i am looking for efficient solution

Comment: In that case, you're treating insertions and deletions differently. Deleting column 4 (zero-indexed) from `1,2,3,5,9,7,8,12` leaves `1,2,3,5,7,8,12`. Deleting column 7 from that is impossible since the highest column is now 6. Please clarify.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes you can consider that as different .

Comment: Since there is gigabytes of data, have you considered putting all the data into a [SQLite database](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite) and manipulating it efficiently there?

Comment: I had not had discussion on this but i am not sure how efficient it would be first putting it there , then modifying it and then retrieving it again in flat file as modified data needs to be feed to another application in flat file

Answer (score 2):

When removing the columns, the indices of the columns to be added might change. Therefore, normalize the indices at the beginning: sort them numerically in descending order, and decrease each index to be added by the number of removed columns it follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my @delete = (4, 7);
my @add    = (3, 5);

# Normalize the arrays.
@delete = sort { $b <=> $a } @delete;
@add    = sort { $b <=> $a } @add;
for my $i (@delete) {
    $_ > $i && --$_ for @add;
}

while (my $line = <>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @columns = split /,/, $line;
    splice @columns, $_, 1      for @delete;
    splice @columns, $_, 0, q() for @add;
    say join ',', @columns;
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me but i want the indices's if columns to be added to change. I have a reference header say `C1,C2,C3,C8,C9` so all my other line whose header can be like `C1,C2,C8,C9,C10` needs to be made as  per reference header. Its just that missing column in second header must be replaced by `,` so it would look like `C1,C2,,C8,C9` . Note C10 is deleted and missing C3 is replaced by `, ,`

Comment: @Invictus: I don't understand.